# Unable to add scala-reflect as a dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I can't add `scala-reflect` as dependency. My `project/build.sbt` looks like this:

```
//the name of the project, will become the name of the war file when you run the package command.
name := "Test-SBT"

version := "1.0"

//specify which Scala version we are using in this project.
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies <++= (scalaVersion)(sv =>
  Seq(
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.3",
    "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.3"
  )
)
```

And `project/build.properties`

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

And here is my Main class:

```
object Main1 extends App {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
  val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  //......
}
```

It says `object runtime is not a member of package reflect`. Of course, I did "gen-idea", "clean" and other things. What's up with that?

Comment: Are you sure, you are showing `project/build.sbt` in the first listing, not just `build.sbt`?

Comment: @laughedelic absolutely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing here due the question by @laughedelic.

The build.sbt should be in the root. Assuming the project you are writing is in `test-sbt`, you should end up with structure similar to:

```
test-sbt/build.sbt 
test-sbt/project
```

Otherwise the `build.sbt` is used in creating the "internal compile project" used by SBT.

A deeper explanation can be found at SBT's docs [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html).

Comment: Whay, I thought it should be in project directory, not in the root one.